# Numerical bivariate integration in Java

Tags: java, numerical-integration

Is it possible to perform numerical bivariate integration (integration of functions with two variables) in Java?

I have looked at [How to solve an Integral in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381817/how-to-solve-an-integral-in-java), but it only explains univariate integration (one variable).

Comment: can you give the function you are aiming to do integration off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible. You may look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIK3ZXVzEdM) to see how you can integrate functions with two variables. You may consider to look into the [java implementation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/93integration/SimpsonsRule.java) of [Simpson's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html) which is a popular technique to approximate the integral of a function using quadratic polynomials. I don't have the perfect answer of your question, so you should try other approaches too.

Comment: Not the only or best way.  The choice of algorithm would depend on the function.  This is a good, general answer but may not be the last word.

Comment: @duffymo i agree. i have just suggested one possible direction to look at!

Comment: I know that. The comment is intended for the OP, not you.