# How to integrate y(x) using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am looking for the java Apache Commons Math equivalent of the python's scipy integration of y(x) using samples along the given axis and the composite Simpson’s rule:

```
data = df.Y.values
samples = df.X.values
result = scipy.integrate.simps(data , samples)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3381909/14955

Comment: Create a UnivariateFunction from your data and do it as in these JUnit tests https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/master/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math4/analysis/integration/SimpsonIntegratorTest.java ?